# How to download picture from Firebase storage on web?

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-storage, download

I'm trying to download a picture from firebase storage and I'm coming across errors.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9onDz.png)

i don't get it what's wrong in it. PLease help
[This is a snapshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dzZU.png)

Comment: Instead of posting links to screenshots of text, post the actual text of those images into the question itself.

Comment: Bro This is my first time on stack overflow I can't post it. They don't let me do it for now

Comment: Everyone can add text to a question. Click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45732802/edit) link under your question, add the code, indent if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, try changing storage.ref(...your path); to storage().ref().child(...your path);

Answer (score 0):

**Try reading this** [Download Files on Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files)

> **You Config Storage Rules ?** [Storage Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start)

Comment: This is the code I'm following actually. I've shared the snap of my code please have a look

Comment: you set firebase.initializeApp(config);  ?